# I'm trying to web scrape a webpage and store the data in a CSV file. But I can't seem to get my code to work

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to web scrape from this link, https://www.premierleague.com/stats/top/players/goals?se=-1
And I don't seem to be successful.

Below is the code I tried.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv`

url = "https://www.premierleague.com/stats/top/players/goals?se=-1"
html = urlopen(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

#print(bs)

listings = []

for rows in bs.find_all("tr"):
 if("oddrow" in rows["class"]) or ("evenrow" in rows["class"]):
    name = rows.find("div", class_="playerName").a.get_text()
    country = rows.find_all("td")[1].get_text()
    goals = rows.find_all("td")[4].get_text()
    listings.append([name, country, goals])

with open("EPL_TEST.csv", 'a', encoding = 'utf-8') as toWrite:
    writer = csv.writer(toWrite)
    writer.writerows(listings)

print("Data Fetched")
```

This is the error I'm getting: `C:\Users\Siddhardh\Desktop\Python\Projects\FinalProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Siddhardh/Desktop/Python/Projects/FinalProject/Scraping.py`
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/Siddhardh/Desktop/Python/Projects/FinalProject/Scraping.py", line 16, in <module>`
`if("oddrow" in rows["class"]) or ("evenrow" in rows["class"]): File "C:\Users\Siddhardh\Desktop\Python\Projects\FinalProject\venv\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1016, in __getitem__ return self.attrs[key] KeyError: 'class'`

`Process finished with exit code 1`

I need to get the names, country and goals of all the players into a CSV file.

P.S. Pardon my editing skills. This is my first post here. I'll learn.

Comment: Did you check out either of the answers @Siddarth Krishna S? People spend their time solving issues, so try not to be indifferent. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry. Yes, the people have been helpful. I've just been out of town without my laptop. Just got back to check out these comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the script below to get all the names traversing multiple pages along with a data ridden csv file. You can use chrome dev tools to get the link I've used within the script. Using that link you will get json response. Modify to get all the other fields.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/stats/ranked/players/goals?page={}&pageSize=20&comps=1&compCodeForActivePlayer=EN_PR&altIds=true"

headers = {
    'Origin': 'https://www.premierleague.com',
}

def get_items(link,page):
    while True:
        res = requests.get(link.format(page),headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
        if not len(res.json()['stats']['content']):break
        for item in res.json()['stats']['content']:
            player_name = item['owner']['name']['display']
            yield player_name

        page+=1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    page = 112
    with open("player_info.csv","w", newline="") as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        writer.writerow(['page','player'])
        for name in get_items(url,page):
            writer.writerow([name])
```

I used `page = 112` to get all the names from that page onward. Feel free to make it `0` to get the names from start to the end.

Comment: Yes. That's how I need it and your code works. But my CSV contains only one page. I need to do it across multiple pages and I tried looping the scarping. Didn't work out.

Comment: So I modify for country and goals and then add then to a CSV like you did in the original reply, right?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. Can you help me with it?

Comment: It's unclear what you meant by `doesn't seem to be working` as I find it working in the right way @Siddarth Krishna S.

Comment: Are you getting the names of all the players past page 1?

Comment: Yeah, all of them.

Comment: I got all the data. But I can't seem to write them into the CSV like before.

Comment: Check out the edit @Siddarth Krishna S. If you have further questions, do create another post. Btw, make sure to accept it as a solution by ticking the grayed out checkmark next to my answer if it serves the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have to change the middle section of your code to this:

```
listings = []

names = bs.find_all("td",scopr="row")
countries = bs.find_all("span",  {"class": "playerCountry"})
goals = bs.find_all("td",class_="mainStat")
for name, country, goal in zip(names,countries,goals):    
    listings.append([name.text.strip(), country.text.strip(), goal.text.strip()])
```

Printing out `listings` results in this output:

> ['Alan Shearer', 'England', '260']
>   ['Wayne Rooney', 'England', '208']
>   ['Andrew Cole', 'England', '187']

etc.